# how to make jumbotron responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image inside the jumbotron when the browser reaches mobile view, the jumbotron is below the image and the image decreases in size the image is suppose to be responsive as it is but i cant seem to make the jumbotron decrease in height when in mobile view.

https://codepen.io/Abdelrahmanyassin/pen/MWaVwpq

```
<style type="text/css">
  .card {
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 50px 10px #888888;
  }

  .jumbotron {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 47rem;
    background-size: 100% ;
  }

  .jumbotronheader {
    background-image: url("C:/Users/abdul/OneDrive/Desktop/Moataz/Designs/Enterprize Innovation Audit Main Elements.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
</style>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotronheader " style=" width:100%; height: 54rem; ">
  <container>
    <h1 class=" jumbo display-auto"></h1>
    <p class=" jumbo lead"></p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p></p>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropbtn pull-right">Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">A0</a>
        <a href="#">A1</a>
        <a href="#">A2</a>
        <a href="#">A3</a>
        <a href="#">A4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </container>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap the cdn is included in my code

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code or link to codepen.io /jsfiddle.net so that community members can guide you on various suggestions. I see that the code you shared is incomplete to address your issue. Inline style `height: 54rems` applied on `jumbotron` div is not valid. Read some more details on how to use media query to handle [responsive design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp). Make use of Chrome developer tools to inspect the element and see the styles applied.

Comment: You can use some placeholder image (https://placehold.it) for the community users to see your actual issue, as the image path given `.jumbotronheader` is referring to local path in your question as well as in codepen.